# From Java, how to find out the physical location (city, country) of the computer where it's running?

Tags: java, database, java-native-interface, location, geoip

Is it possible to know from Java where the computer where it's running is? If not, how can I do it using JNI? Or any scripts?
I'm building a Java system, and on login, I'm supposed to register on the database who's logging in, where and when. I just don't know how to get the where.

Comment: Assuming you're using servlets, get the IP and use a region lookup table.  (No, you won't get city accuracy with this, but that's as good as you get without the user actually telling you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you can get the client to send in some sort of coordinates (like GPS), you could use some IP-based solution, such as [MaxMind GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location). They have a `lite` versions of the [city](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) and [country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) locating databases, which are free but less accurate. There are [APIs](http://www.maxmind.com/app/api) available for most common languages.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ip-address to locate the country where the computer is running. There are several ip address databases available - just look them up in a search machine.